# AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'

Tags: python

So I'm making a music bot and I have everything working except one thing, I've tried fixing it and I've looked around stackoverflow for answers, but no one has the same problem as me.

When I run the bot the first time and do +play the bot joins and works perfectly but on the second try is when things get weird, and it just doesn't join the vc and gives me this error message:

```
nextcord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'Member' object has no attribute 'voice_channel'
```

and here is the part of the file that has the error:

```
from tkinter import BOTH
from types import coroutine
from discord import BotIntegration
import nextcord, os, random, json, datetime, humanfriendly, random, wavelink
from nextcord import Enum
from nextcord.utils import get
from nextcord.ext import commands

intents = nextcord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

class CustomHelpCommand(commands.HelpCommand):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    async def send_bot_help(self, mapping):
        for cog in mapping:
            await self.get_destination().send(f'{cog.qualified_name}: {[command.name for command in mapping[cog]]}')

    async def send_cog_help(self, cog):
        await self.get_destination().send(f'{cog.qualified_name}: {[command.name for command in cog.get_commands()]}')

    async def send_group_help(self, group):
        await self.get_destination().send(f'{group.name}: {[command.name for index, command in enumerate(group.commands)]}')
 
    async def send_command_help(self,command):
        await self.get_destination().send(command.name)

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = '+', intents=intents, help_command=commands.MinimalHelpCommand())

@client.event
async def on_ready():
        await client.change_presence(status=nextcord.Status.dnd, activity=nextcord.Game('Listening to Vinality'))
        print('Listening to Mods.')
        client.loop.create_task(node_connect())


@client.event
async def node_connect():
            await client.wait_until_ready()
            await wavelink.NodePool.create_node(bot = client, host="jp-lava.islantay.tk", port=443, password="AmeliaWatsonisTheBest**!", https=True)

@client.event
async def on_wavelink_node_ready(node: wavelink.Node):
        print(f'Node {node.identifier} is ready')

@client.command()
async def play(ctx: commands.Context, *, search: wavelink.YouTubeTrack):
        if not ctx.voice_client:
            vc: wavelink.Player = await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect(cls=wavelink.Player)
        elif not ctx.author.voice_channel:
            return await ctx.send("You are not in a Voice Channel.")
        else:
            vc: wavelink.Player = ctx.voice_client

        await vc.play(search)
```

I believe the part that is making the error is the play command.

Comment: Did you mean `ctx.author.voice_client`

Comment: @DelriusEuphoria that was the original code but it just didnt work even on the first try so I changed it to ctx.author.voice_channel , now I just need to find out why I cant run it multiple times in one instance